# Reading Boot Sector on Windows

Tags: python, windows, mbr

I created a little program on python that reads the boot sector at a low level so it will not corrupt the device. I successfully ran this program yesterday in Linux and I got the idea to do the same thing in Windows. But the only problem that came was that I wasn't enabled to read for example:`\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1`, the boot partition or `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0`, the raw disk 0. Each time that I try it throws an error: `No such a file or a directory`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try with the `\\.` prefix?  That is `open("\\\\.\\Device\\Harddisk0\\Partition1")`

Comment: you cannot use the same method: boot sector is not mapped on a file. Where did you read that it was possible like that on windows?

Comment: It gives me the same error

Comment: `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0` is in the object namespace. The Windows API makes selective use of this namespace, e.g. global symbolic links to devices are created in `\GLOBAL??`, e.g. `C:` => `\Device\HarddiskVolume2`. The legacy DOS namespace lets you use *some* device links here, such as drive letters and legacy DOS devices such as `CON`, but to access everything you need one of the WinAPI device prefixes, either ``\\.\`` (some path processing and forward slash is allowed, but limited to `MAX_PATH` characters) or ``\\?\`` (no path processing; must be Unicode and use backslash).

Comment: The link you're looking for is `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`, which opens `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0`. Similarly `\\.\PhysicalDrive1` opens `\Device\Harddisk1\DR1`. The other one, `\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1` is a volume, not a disk. You can just open the volume drive letter or GUID mountpoint, e.g. `\\.\C:`. But you can't hard code this. You have to use the API to map a volume by drive letter, GUID volume name, or NTFS mount point to a physical disk number.

Comment: I tried `t = open(r"\\.\PhysicalDrive0")` and it gets me the error : `Permission Denied`. So I did it in my command line as administrator and it gave me : `OSError: [WinError 1] Incorrect Function`

Comment: Python's high-level I/O tries to stat the file, which fails. Use `disk_fd = os.open( r"\\.\PhysicalDrive0", os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY);` `data = os.read(disk_fd, 512);` `os.close(disk_fd)`.

Comment: Exactly what are you reading in Linux? We need to know whether you're trying to read a master boot record / GUID partition table on the disk or the volume boot record on the volume. If you want to read the VBR for the system disk, open `'\\.\%s' % os.environ['SystemDrive']`. This will almost always be `\\.\C:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Correct Way To Do It Is:

```
import os
disk_fd = os.open( r"\\.\PhysicalDrive0", os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY)
data = os.read(disk_fd, 512)
os.close(disk_fd)
```

Thanks To @eryksun

Answer (score 0):

all depended from NT or WIN32 api you using. `ZwOpenFile` or `CreateFileW` ?

`\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1` is NT name format and must be used in `ZwOpenFile` or `ZwCreateFile` only.

for use this name in `CreateFileW` you must prefix it by `\\?\globalroot`

so code example - (using both NT and win32 calls in single function)

```
void xxx()
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, L"\\Device\\Harddisk0\\Partition1");

    UCHAR buf[0x200];
    if (0 <= ZwOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT))
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset = {};
        ZwReadFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, buf, sizeof(buf), &ByteOffset, 0);
        ZwClose(hFile);
    }

    hFile = CreateFile(L"\\\\?\\globalroot\\Device\\Harddisk0\\Partition1", FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS,
        0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        OVERLAPPED ov = {};
        ULONG n;
        ReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf), &n, &ov);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```

also you can use next SymbolicLinks with `CreateFileW` :

- `\\?\Harddisk<X>Partition<Y>` - for partition  (1,2,..) on HardDisk
   (0,1,..)
- `\\?\PhysicalDrive<X>` for HardDisk  (0,1,..)

all depend from - how you got this paths ? or you simply hardcode it ?

Comment: That's just a link to the volume, e.g. `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`, so why wouldn't you just open the conventional drive letter, GUID volume name, or NTFS mount point? For example, `\\.\C:`. Otherwise if you wanted to open the underlying disk(s), you'd have to open the volume and get the disk extents via [`IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365194), and open the corresponding `\\.\PhysicalDrive[N]`. That's all without any need to refer to the native object namespace, which should be avoided in Windows programming. Microsoft doesn't support it.

Comment: @eryksun - about how/which names use- depend from how OP got (or calculate) `\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1` or he simply hardcode it ? i not try cover here how need enumerate/open disks, partition, volumes. what is difference between this objects. i only explain the different in name format  for *concrete hardcoded name*

Comment: I'm just explaining that these native object paths shouldn't be used in Windows user-mode programming unless there's no other way to get something done. In this case it's not necessary.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, i listen this already many time :) i nothing concrete advice to use (nt or win32 api) simply show code for both case and different in names ( `\\?\globalroot` prefix) however main question here - what is goal of OP, how correct enumerate disks or partitions (volumes).. i not cover this. may be better delete my answer at all ?